# Input still responding to mouse events after 'disabled' attribute set

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Problem: I'm attempting to disable a radio button by using the code below. This always dims the radio button, but it still responds to mouse events (in Opera, the button is actually selected with a tick mark, but the tick is dimmed).

```
$('input:radio[name=admission1][value=1]').attr("disabled", true);
$('#radioAMethod').buttonset("refresh");
...
$(function(){
   $('#admissionCheckBox1').click(function(){
      ...still executed when button dimmed... why?
   });
});
```

I've also tried

```
$('input:radio[name=admission1][value=1]').prop("disabled", true);
$('input:radio[name=admission1][value=1]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

but it makes no difference.
How can I disable mouse actions on the button? Thanks.

### EDIT

Some html:

```
<div id="radioAMethod" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all effect">
   <h4 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Admission method</h4>
   <input type ="radio" 
          name ="admission1" 
          id   ="admissionCheckBox0"
          value="0" 
          checked="checked"/>M1<br/>
   <input type ="radio" 
          name ="admission1" 
          id   ="admissionCheckBox1"
          value="1"/>M2<br/>
   <input type ="radio" 
          name ="admission1" 
          id   ="admissionCheckBox2"
          value="other"/>M3<br/>
```

The code in the click function I showed above does correctly fire when the button is not disabled, and is clicked. Thanks.

### EDIT 2

Should have said, but only just realised - this code uses the buttons from http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/. If the code should work, then I guess the problem is actually in his JS somewhere.

Comment: Your selector refers to a radio, but the ID is named checkbox. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: What browser? Did you try with other browser(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing something wrong

in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VVP5G/ you'll see a working situation where the disabled input doesn't trigger the click event.

Are you sure the ID correspond to the radio input?

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle code. Curious. My button clearly dims when 'disable' is applied, but I still get a mouse event on click. I can see it on the front end, as well being sure that the ID is correct. What confuses me is this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703098/opera-firing-mouse-events-on-disabled-input-element, where an Opera dev says "The "disabled" attribute merely means that the element will not do its normal action when clicked. I don't really see any reason why setting disabled should prevent firing mouseover/move".